# Locating loaded dylibs

Tags: objective-c, macos, objective-c++, dylib

I'm pretty new to Apple world, so sorry for newbie question.

I got a process id of a running process on my macos, and then using `vmmap` tried to get some information about the loaded dylibs in that process,

```
% vmmap 2081 | grep dylib
...
...
...
__DATA                   7ffa5b08c410-7ffa5b08c418 [     8      8     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreFSCache.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b08c418-7ffa5b08c8d0 [  1208   1208     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b08dc78-7ffa5b08dd58 [   224    224     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b08dd58-7ffa5b08dee8 [   400    400     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b08dee8-7ffa5b08df58 [   112    112     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b08df60-7ffa5b08e5a0 [  1600   1600     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
__DATA                   7ffa5b093280-7ffa5b093288 [     8      8     0K     0K] rw-/rw- SM=COW          /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
...
...
...
```

But when I check the path for those dylibs I cannot find them, below is the few random that I tried,

```
% ls /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libXTFontStaticRegistryData.dylib
ls: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libXTFontStaticRegistryData.dylib: No such file or directory

% ls /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
ls: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib: No such file or directory
```

- Is there any better way to get the loaded libraries in a running process, or an executable?
- How can I get the actual path of those dylib files(mostly OS related, not any library that I wrote)?

Thanks